# Error while importing Quandl to python shell

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, quandl

I have already installed Quandl library along with sci-kit learn, matplotlib and pandas through pip but while importing the quandl library, it is showing error.

I have attached the screenshots here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `import quandl` - all lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct name is `quandl`, all lowercase as [shown in the docs](https://docs.quandl.com/docs/python-installation). Therefore try

```
import quandl
```

Comment: Thank you. It's such a silly question but I was misguided by a video.

Comment: You're welcome, everyone starts small. Fell free to mark my answer as accepted if it solves your problem.